# How does one convert data in API Weather - Sunrise/Sunset in swift code?

Tags: swift

this is the `sysDictionary`

```
"sys":{"type":1,"id":3721,"message":0.0038,"country":"CA","sunrise":1521544743,"sunset":1521588663}
```

---

```
if let sysDictionary = jsonObj!.value(forKey: "sys") as? NSDictionary { 
   if let sunrise = sysDictionary.value(forKey: "sunrise"){

     DispatchQueue.main.async { 
        self.sunriseLabel.text = "Sunrise: (sunrise)"

// this code is displaying the sunrise 1521544743 into my app not hrs/mins/sec format,
```

Comment: *Convert* to what?

Comment: `sunrise` and `sunset` look like unix epoch timestamps

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a [tour] in StackOverflow and check [ask] a good question!

Comment: You mean you want to convert a UNIX timestamp to a `Date` object? Just use `Date(timeIntervalSince1970:)`.

Comment: Here is my code to get it,

Comment: if let sysDictionary = jsonObj!.value(forKey: "sys") as? NSDictionary {
                        if let sunrise = sysDictionary.value(forKey: "sunrise"){
                            
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                self.sunriseLabel.text = "Sunrise: \(sunrise)"

Comment: And it just displays sunrise 1521544743 in my app

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49415666/edit) your question to add information.

Comment: Okay done, please re-check...

Answer (score 2):

The sunrise and sunset times look like unix timestamps. You can create a `Date` object from these to use in your app using the initialiser `Date(timeIntervalSince1970: sunrise)`.

In order to actually display this date in your user interface, you will want to use a `DateFormatter`, which takes in a `Date`, and outputs a human readable string ready to put into your label.

Here is an example of how to achieve this.

```
if let jsonObj = jsonObj as? [String: Any],
    let sysDictionary = jsonObj["sys"] as? [String: Any],
    let sunrise = sysDictionary["sunrise"] as? NSNumber {

    let sunriseDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: sunrise.doubleValue)
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .none
    formatter.timeStyle = .medium

    let formattedTime = formatter.string(from: sunriseDate)
    print(formattedTime)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.sunriseLabel.text = "Sunrise: \(formattedTime)"
    }
}

// prints "12:19:03 AM" using your example JSON
```

---

To convert the speed in your JSON there are two options, the first being doing it yourself:

```
let ms: Double = 1
let kmh = ms * 60 * 60 / 1000
print(kmh)
// prints 3.6
```

Or you can use Foundation to do the conversion for you and provide clarity with what you are doing (IMO the recommended approach):

```
var measurement = Measurement(value: 1, unit: UnitSpeed.metersPerSecond)
measurement.convert(to: .kilometersPerHour)
print(measurement.value)
// prints 3.5999971200023

let speedFormatter = MeasurementFormatter()
speedFormatter.unitOptions = .providedUnit
speedFormatter.unitStyle = .medium
let formattedSpeed = speedFormatter.string(from: measurement)
print(formattedSpeed)
// prints "3.6 kph"
```

Comment: Jake, thank you so much, this works perfectly for both Sunset and Sunrise, and thank you for introducing me to DateFormatter. I have one more question if possible, is there a code for a conversion? ie data for Wind Speed comes out as m/s (meters per second) how would one convert that to KPH?

Comment: I have edited my answer to include speed conversions.